# Pass string instead of file to openssl_pkcs7_sign()

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I am looking into php openSSL library and need to sign a string using pub and priv key. The function [`openssl_pkcs7_sign()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php) from documentation it seem to take the file path as a file parameter but I have string in a variable that I need to encrypt. I see all of its examples points to writing files.

Is there any way I can pass the string into the function? Or perhaps some other functions available? Writing file to disk doesn't seem very practical for my use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, **it's not possible**.

According to [the source code of OpenSSL PHP extension](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L5287), they use openssl library function [PKCS7_sign](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:PKCS7_sign(3)).

This function takes a [BIO](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/BIO) stream as input, which can be a buffer.

However, in OpenSSL PHP extension, [the BIO stream is created as a file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L5273), taking the filename as a parameter.

You can ask for the implementation of this new feature through an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto), but you probably want to discuss the matter in the internals mailing list first.